# Upload pdf to Google Cloud Bucket with python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I am new to the Google Cloud/Firebase environment and I want to upload pdf files to the storage bucket in firebase.

This is the code I am trying to use (I replaced my project relevant files with capital names):

```
# Use a service account.
cred = credentials.Certificate('CERTIFICATE')

app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

def upload_pdf_to_storage(pdf_path, bucket_name, destination_blob_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    
    blob.upload_from_filename(pdf_path)

# Usage
pdf_path = 'sample_cv.pdf'
bucket_name = "MYBUCKETNAME"
destination_blob_name = "pdfs/pdf_filename.pdf"

upload_pdf_to_storage(pdf_path, bucket_name, destination_blob_name)
```

This is the error message I get:
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable

Do you know what I am doing wrong?
Thank you very much :)

Tried to upload pdf in the storage bucket of GC to use them in firebase

Answer (score 0):

**Install the Google Cloud Storage client library**

pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage

**Set up Authentication**

Hope you know this step.

**Upload the PDF to GCS**

Here's a simple Python script to upload a PDF to Google Cloud Storage:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    # Initialize the storage client
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        'YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_PATH')  # replace with the path to your JSON credentials
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    
    # Upload the file
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print(f"File {source_file_name} uploaded to {destination_blob_name}.")

# Use the function
bucket_name = 'YOUR_BUCKET_NAME'  # replace with your bucket name
source_file_name = 'path_to_your_pdf.pdf'  # replace with the path to your PDF
destination_blob_name = 'desired_name_in_gcs.pdf'  # replace with the desired name in GCS

upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name)
```

Replace 'YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_PATH', 'YOUR_BUCKET_NAME', 'path_to_your_pdf.pdf', and 'desired_name_in_gcs.pdf' with the appropriate values.

After running this script, your PDF will be uploaded to the specified bucket in Google Cloud Storage.